# Magic method __str__ is not called on str call

Tags: python, python-3.x, wrapper, magic-methods

I'm the creator of [module-wrapper](https://github.com/rominf/module-wrapper) library and one of the authors of [aioify](https://github.com/yifeikong/aioify) library. The problem arises in magic method wrapping inside `module-wrapper` library (I call `module_wrapper.wrap` from `aioify.aioify`, but that doesn't matter).

I have the following code:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
from aioify import aioify


async def main():
    from pathlib import Path
    # noinspection PyPep8Naming
    AioPath = aioify(obj=Path)
    return await AioPath.create('/tmp')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import asyncio
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    path = loop.run_until_complete(main())
    path_str = str(path)
    print(path_str)
```

I expect to get following output:

```
/tmp
```

But I get this:

```
<module_wrapper.wrap.<locals>.ObjectProxy object at 0x7f64266a9b00>
```

I cannot understand why. When I call:

```py
path_str = path.__str__()
print(path_str)
```

I get what I expect:

```
/tmp
```

When I set the breakpoint [inside](https://github.com/rominf/module-wrapper/blob/master/module_wrapper/__init__.py#L212) magic method wrapper function debugger doesn't stop.

**UPD0:**
To reproduce this you need to install `module-wrapper` and `aioify` (from the tarball because it's not released on PyPI). Don't forget to create virtualenv before!):

```
pip install module-wrapper==0.1.26
pip install https://github.com/yifeikong/aioify/archive/0.3.0.zip
```

Comment: Please update your question with a [mcve]. We can't have links to code that will change as soon as you get an answer...

Comment: Note that magic methods may not follow the normal attribute lookup (ref [special method lookup](https://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-lookup)). Is `__str__` really defined on the class (as opposed to the instance)?

Comment: @Aran-Fey, thank you! I updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally solved it. [mseifert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5393381/mseifert) was right, the problem was that I didn't wrap magic methods of the class. See fixed version on GitHub and on PyPI.